# Clarification on change of variables proof for random variables

Tags: integration, probability-theory, measure-theory

I had this proof in my probability theory class and I hope someone can clarify how the professor went from proving the following proposition from non-negative random variables to general random variables. Here's the theorem:

Let $X$ be a random variable on a probability space $(\Omega,\mathcal{F},P)$ and let $\mu_X(B) = P(X\in B)$ for all borel sets $B$, then
$$\mathbb{E}[X] = \int x\textrm{d}\mu_X(dx)$$
He proves this for $X\geq 0$ and then says that to prove this for general $X$: "we have that $X= X^{+} - X^{-}$ and use the fact that $\mu_{X} = \mu_{X^+} + \mu_{X^{-}}$". Can I please get clarification on this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$EX^{+}=\int x d\mu_{X^{+}}$ and $EX^{-}=\int x d\mu_{X^{-}}$. If $EX$ exists then either $EX^{+}<\infty$ or $EX^{-}<\infty$. In this case it is legitimate to subtract the second equation from then first to get $EX=\int x d\mu(x)$. Similarly, if $\int x d\mu(x)$ exists then subtraction is again permitted. Conclusion: $EX=\int x d\mu(x)$ provided either of the two sides sides exists.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I don't understand how $\int x d\mu_{X^{+}} - \int x d\mu_{X^{-}} = \int x d\mu_X$. Aren't we counting the set $\{0\}$ twice?

Comment: $\int_{\{0\}}x d\mu_X=0=\int_{\{0\}}x d\mu_{X^{+}}=\int_{\{0\}}x d\mu_{X^{-}}$. @user788466